# Create dynamic jQuery slideToggle divs that track clicks with google analytics

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am attempting to read from my database a list of businesses by means of PHP and mySql.  After finding the businesses I want to display, I'd like to list them consecutively inside their own "clickDiv" (this part I already have working).  This "clickDiv" should be clickable to jQuery slideToggle and reveal the body information of each business, which I currently have inside the id=revealPara.

I'd like for the click to be recorded with Google analytics as an event, the name of the business, or "$row['name']".

I've tried to Google my way through this, but so far I've only gotten the toggleSlide to work on the first "clickDiv" listed, and not the following businesses.  As far as the analytics part, I've gotten nowhere.

Here is the current code that I have that successfully builds my list.

```
//select all businesses
///////////////////////

$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM businesses"

$result = mysql_query($sql)
or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
?>

//list businesses
/////////////////

<div id="clickDiv" class="row-fluid" style="background-color:#333333;">
<div class="span4" style="padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img height="75px" width="75px" src="../img/logos/<?php echo $row['logo'];?>"></div>
<div class="span4"><h2 style="color:#01a7c6; padding-top:0px; margin:0;"><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2><p style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px; margin:0"><?php echo $row['address']?></p><p id="revealPara<?php echo $row['id'];?>" style="text-align:center; padding:50px 0"><?php echo $row['body'];?></div>
<div class="span4"><h2><i class="icon-sort-down" style="color:#01a7c6; font-size:1em; padding-right:10px; margin-bottom:0px 0px;"></i></h2></div>
</div>
}

<!-- slide toggle -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clickDiv").click(function(){
    $("#revealPara").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you should only have unique id's for your elements. The way your coding is setup, every business will have an id of "clickDiv".

Secondly, when using jQuery to select an ID, it will only return one, as it only expects to find one, so you won't have  a group returned. If you really want to keep the id the same for all of these elements (not semantic), you could use the $('div[id="clickDiv"]'), as that will return of all of these items and you slider will work.

I would suggest using either a class name of "clickDiv" for each item, and create an ID that is unique to each one (i.e.-#clickDiv1, #clickDiv2, etc.) by using a variable and incrementing it by one each time the while loop runs.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I do want it to be variable, not just one ID.  I've updated the code and added what I believe will work as a unique ID, and changed the clickDiv to class.  Now, how can I set the script to recognize each individual clickDiv(with added ID)?

Comment: Got it!  The problem was I had special characters screwing it up, but your changing to specific id's was also key.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For event tracking, following is a sample.

```
<!-- slide toggle -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickDiv").click(function(){
    $("#revealPara").slideToggle("slow");
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']); // edit this
  });
});
</script>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking

Comment: Thank you for leading me to this.  This was the second part of what I needed answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have an div closing tab errors and syntax errors on your example.

```
<div id="clickDiv" class="row-fluid" style="background-color:#333333;">

     <div class="span4" style="padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;"><img height="75px" width="75px" src="../img/logos/<?php echo $row['logo'];?>">
      </div>

      <div class="span4"><h2 style="color:#01a7c6; padding-top:0px; margin:0;"><p style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px; margin:0"><?php echo $row['address']?></p><p id="revealPara" style="        text-align:center; padding:50px 0"><?php echo $row['body'];?>
      </div>

      <div class="span4"><h2><i class="icon-sort-down" style="color:#01a7c6; font-size:1em; padding-right:10px; margin-bottom:0px 0px;"></i></h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've removed the div, and also added the script that I am attempting to use.  So we're clear, each "clickDiv" should be able to be pressed separately from one another to reveal only that specific business' information.